# list max_size implementation

Tags: c++, stl

When I see the source code, it said that

```
size_type max_size() const
{
    return size_type(-1);
}
```

I don't know why it should return -1, can I return any other integer or char? Does anybody can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`size_type` is presumably unsigned.  That means initializing it to `-1` makes it its maximum value - `0xffffffff` for a 32-bit number or `0xffffffffffffffff` if `size_type` is a 64-bit type.